# Do Java regular expressions support collating sequences?

Tags: java, regex, collation

I am trying the regex `([[.ch.]]*)c` against the test string `chchch`. According to [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html):

> [[.ch.]]*c matches the first to fifth character in the string chchch

When I test it in Java, it indeed matches those characters, but so does `[[ch]]*c`. Thus I am not sure if the collating symbol is respected. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - No.

---

The specification you are reading/quoting is the Open Group's SUS (**S**ingle **U**NIX® **S**pecification) version of  the regular expression part of IEEE's POSIX (**P**ortable **O**perating **S**ystem **I**nterface for uni**X**) collection of standards. (See https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html ¹)

In general, only POSIX-compliant regular expression engines fully support [POSIX bracket expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), which are essentially what other regex flavors call character classes but with a few special features, one being that `[.` and `.]` are interpreted as the start and end of a collating sequence when used within the expressions.

Unfortunately, very few regex engines are POSIX-compliant and, in fact, some claiming to implement POSIX regexes just use the regular expression syntax defined by POSIX and don't have full [locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/locale.html) support. Thus they don't implement all/any of the bracket expression features/quirks.

Java's regular expressions are in no way POSIX-compliant, as can be seen from this [Regular Expression Engine Comparison Chart](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816#regular-expression-engine-comparison-chart) ². Its `regex` package implements a "Perl-like" regex engine, missing a few features (e.g. conditional expressions and comments), but including some extra ones (e.g. possessive quantifiers and variable-length, but finite, look-behind assertions).

Neither Perl nor Java support the collation-related bracket delimiters `[=` and `=]` (character equivalence), or `[.` and `.]` (collating sequence). Perl does support character classes using the POSIX `[:` and `:]` delimiters, but Java only supports them using the `\p` operator (with a few caveats as explained [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)).

So, what is going on with the regex `[[.ch.]]*c` in Java? (I'm ignoring the capturing group as it doesn't change the analysis.)

Well, it turns out that Java's `regex` package supports [unions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) in its character classes. This is achieved by nesting. For example, `[set1[set2]]` is equivalent to `[set3]` where the characters in `set3` are the union of the characters in `set1` and the characters in `set2`. (As an aside, note that `[[set1][set2]]` and `[[set1]set2]` also produce the same result.)

So, `[[.ch.]]` is simply the character class containing the union of an empty set of characters with the set of characters in the character class `[.ch.]`, so basically it's the same as the character class `[.ch.]`. This is equivalent to `[.ch]` (since the second `.` is redundant) and thus `[[.ch.]]*c` is the same as `[.ch]*c`.

Similarly, `[[ch]]*c` simplifies to `[ch]*c`.

Finally, since there aren't any `.` characters in the string `chchch`, the regexes `[.ch]*c` and `[ch]*c` will produce the same result. (Try testing against the string `c.hchch` to see the difference and prove the above.)

---

**Notes:**

This is not a very good example for either demonstrating collating sequences or for detecting if they are implemented, as `[[.ch.]]*c` will match `chchc` in `chchch` both when collating sequences are supported (and `ch` is a valid sequence in the current locale) and when they are not but unions are.

A much better demo/test is to use the regex `[[.ch.]]` with the test string `ch`:

- Collating sequences are supported if `ch` is matched.
- Any other match means they are not.
- They *may* be supported if an error is returned, as this is what happens if `ch` is not a valid sequence in the current locale (it's a valid collating sequence in the Czech locale):

  - If the error specifies that `ch` is not a valid collating sequence, then they *are* supported.
  - If the error returned is that the delimiter/token `[.` and/or `.]` is invalid/unsupported, then collating sequences are *not* supported.
  - If the error is ambiguous, or for a guaranteed way to check for support, you need to switch to the Czech locale (and confirm that `ch` is indeed a valid collating sequence) or switch to any other locale that has at least one defined collating sequence which can be used instead of `ch`.

---

¹ <sub>I am neither Jan Goyvaerts nor in no way affiliated with the Regular-Expressions.info site.</sub>
² <sub>Nor am I CMCDragonkai.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. One note, Java does in fact support comments, provided you turn on comments mode either by passing in the Pattern.COMMENTS flag or embed the (?x) flag.

Comment: @VictorGrazi You're welcome. I'm a little confused, though. What is the reference to comments mode all about? AFAIK comments have to do with allowing embedded comments in a regex. I don't see how this is relevant to my answer.

Comment: you said Java's "regex package implements a "Perl-like" regex engine, missing a few features (e.g. conditional expressions and comments)". I was just correcting that, Java is not missing comments support. You can specify (?x) in your pattern, so that whitespace is ignored, and # is interpreted as a comment indicator. Right?